# Vue routes stop working once building the app for production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have build a vue app and it runs without any issue in the development version (`npm run dev`) however once I build it (`npm run build`), only the home page on url/ can be accessed and any other route will just return 404. To serve the page I tried to upload it to render.com or running it locally with `npm run build` and `serve -S dist` in both just the HomePage can be accessed.

main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

import router from "./router";
// you may want to clean default main.css file
// since default options may no satisfy you.

import "./assets/main.css";

const app = createApp(App);
// the two next lines will make bootstrap available to your
// application if bootstrap has been installed.
// Instalation instructions are available later in this guide

app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");

import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

router/index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import HomeView from "../views/HomeView.vue";
import JoinerView from "../views/joiner.vue";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: HomeView,
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      name: "about",
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import("../views/AboutView.vue"),
    },
    {
      path: "/joiner",
      name: "join",
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => JoinerView,
    },
    {
      path: "/waiting/:id",
      name: "waiting",
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import("../views/waiting.vue"),
    },
    {
      path: "/question/:id",
      name: "question",
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import("../views/question.vue"),
    },
    {
      path: "/waitingAnswer/:id",
      name: "waitingAnswer",
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import("../views/waitingAnswer.vue"),
    },
    {
      path: "/answer/:id",
      name: "answer",
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import("../views/answer.vue"),
    },
  ],
});

export default router;
```

vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: its common, research SPA fallback, you'll need to setup [rewrites](https://github.com/vercel/serve-handler#rewrites-array) so requests to them pages point to /dist/index.html then in turn that fires up routing to load the correct page